# Bash for loop not working over large dataset in OSX

Tags: macos, bash

I have a directory with a large number of sub-directories some of which have several zip files in them. I'm trying to write a bash script that will go through the directories and look for the name "Archive-foo" enter the sub-directory and if it contains zip files unzip them and then trash the zip files.

The script I wrote works on my test directories (5 sub directories) but when I tried to use it on the main archive directory (1200+ sub-directories) it fails to do anything.

Is there a max number of items a for loop can cycle through?

here's my code

```
#!/bin/bash
SAVEIFS=$IFS
IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b")
NUMBER=0
for i in $( ls )
do
#echo "$i"" is in the Top Level"
NUMBER=$[NUMBER+1]
if ($(test -d "$i")) 
then
    #echo "$i"" is a Directory"
    if [[ "$i" == *Archive* ]]
    then
        #echo "$i"" has Archive in the name"
        cd "$i" 
        unzip -n "*".zip
        mv *.zip ~/.Trash
    #else
        #echo "$i"" does not have Archive in the name"
    fi
 #else
    #echo "$i"" is NOT a Directory skipping"
fi
done
echo "$NUMBER of items"
IFS=$SAVEIFS
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a limit on the size of command lines, and `for i in $( ls )` may be exceeding it.

Try this syntax instead:

```
ls | while read i;
do
  ...
done
```

The only problem with this is that the pipeline runs the `while` loop in a subshell, so assignments to `NUMBER` won't persist into the original shell process. You can have the loop prints a line whenever it processes a line, and pipe the whole loop to `wc -l` to count the number of lines.

Answer (score 3):

[Barmer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17890902/368630) answer hit the issue on the nose. Using `for file in $(...)` as loop headers is not a very good idea:

- **It is slower**: The shell executes what is in `$(..)` first, then runs the `for` loop. It can't start the `for` until `$(...)` finishes.
- **It can overrun the command line buffer**: The shell executes `$(..)` and then puts it on the command line. The command line buffer may be about 32 Kilobytes, maybe more now, but if you have 10,000 files and each file is averaging 20 characters, you end up with over a 200Kb command line buffer,
- **For loops are terrible at handling bad file names**: If file names have white spaces in them, each word is treated like a file.

A much better construct is:

```
find . ... -print0 | while read -d $\0 file
do
   ...
done
```

- This can execute the `while read` loop while the `find` is executing, making it faster.
- This can't overrun the command line buffer.
- Most importantly, this construct handles almost any type of file name. The `find` will return each file separated by a `NUL` character - a character that cannot be in a file name. The `-d $\0` tells the `read` command that the `NUL` character is the delimiter between file names. This handles spaces, tabs, and even *new lines* in file names.

The `find` is also very flexible. You can limit the list to only files, files in a particular age range, etc. The most common ones needed to replae `for` loops are:

```
$ find . -depth 1
```

acts just like `ls -a`:

```
$ find . \! -name ".*" -prune -a  -depth 1
```

Acts just like `ls`, and will skip over files names that begin with `.`.

Comment: The only issue I ran into using the find command is unzip extracts all of the files to the directory your running the find command from.